# Get Entry Edit Link in Twig

Tags: templating, control-panel

I want to add an "Edit entry" button on each page for admin users. Am I overlooking a simple way to output the Edit link to the CP edit page for the current entry? Curious if there is something like `{{ entry.editLink }}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is! It's called [cpEditUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel#cpEditUrl-detail).

```
{% if currentUser %}
   {% if currentUser.isInGroup('admin') %}
       <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">Edit entry</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Or shorter (thanks to MISC):

```
{% if currentUser.admin %}
    <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">Edit entry</a>
{% endif %}
```

Or forget user group altogether (thanks to Phil Gyford and bennobo):

```
{% if entry.isEditable() %}
    <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">Edit entry</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You are the man, Douglas!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `{% if entry.isEditable() %}` as in this answer: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-grant-front-end-access-to-an-entry-that-belongs-to-the-current-user

Comment: Or even shorter: {% if currentUser.admin %}

Comment: I think that `{% if entry.isEditable() %}` is the way to go as it totally forgets the user/group logic. It's just one simple question: **Can you edit?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is Craft CMS 3 solution:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/quick-edit

It works both with entries and categories and it takes multiple things into account while deciding if edit link should be displayed:

- If the current user has access rights to control panel?
- If the current user has rights to edit current entry/category?
- If entry/category is not displayed through live preview?