# Front-end link to Clear Cache?

Tags: templating, craft3

I currently implemented a fixed position edit button in the front-end when a user is logged in based on this " [Get Entry Edit Link in Twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7104/get-entry-edit-link-in-twig) " Is there a version of this link, but to Clear Cache?

Comment: No because clearing caches only works via ajax request as you can see here https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php#L329. Do you want to perform one?

Comment: That would be a great option..yes.

Comment: Template caches will get broken regardless of whether the changes were made in the AdminCP or your front end form.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/24166/basic-ajax-how-to/24167#24167) to get to know how to create a basic ajax request

And change the route to

```
action: 'utilities/clear-caches-perform-action',
caches: '*'
```